# Casting Objects to <T>-type

Tags: java, generics, casting, content-type

I'm implementing List interface to a class which stores data in a `<T>` type array. This raises problems with methods that take Collection as parameters, since collection stores it's objects as `Object`. How can I transform `Object` to `T` ? Simple casting doesn't work.

```
class MyCollection<T> implements List<T>{
    T[] tab;

    MyCollection() {
        this.tab = (T[])new Object[10];
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection c){
        for(Object o : c){
            o = (T)o;
            for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
                tab[i] = o;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying :

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c)
```

but it fails with :

`public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)` since I cannot change the Collection type here :/

```
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c){
    boolean result = false;
    for(T t : c){
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How you are implementing `retainAll(Coll...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the right approach ?

Yes, that is correct approach.  That is what the interface is defined as (except that the interface uses `E`, but that doesn't matter).

Note that your `addAll` should return a `boolean`.  Also, you dont need to cast in `addAll` that you have implemented.  Change your loop instead:

```
   for(T o : c){...}
```

And your `retainAll` should be fine as well, as long as you return a `boolean`.

EDIT:

For your `retainAll` implementation, there shouldn't be a need to iterate over the passed in `Collection<?>` and cast to a `T`.  Consider iterating over your `tab` backing array and seeing if each instance is contained in the passed in `Collection<?> c`.  If for some reason you absolutely need to use the items within `c` as `T`s, you can cast.

Comment: in retainAll I'm getting 'incompatible types. Required T, found java.lang.Object'

Answer (score 1):

You should be defining your addAll method like this:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {...}
```

That's how it's defined in the Java API

Comment: And if retainAll gives you trouble, you should override the retain all to take in Collection<? extends T> as well.  The other suggestions work, but this one is "more correct" in my view.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to `T` is not required to implement `retainAll(...)`.  For example:

```
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c){
    boolean result = false;
    Iterator<T> it = this.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        T t : it.next();
        if (!c.contains(t)) {
            it.remove();
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```