# Incompatible types generics Java

Tags: java, generics

I did this code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Node<T> {
private T data;
private LinkedList<T> children;
public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = new LinkedList<T>();
}
public T getData() {
    return this.data;
}
public LinkedList<T> getChildren(){
    return this.children;
}
}


public class Graph <T> implements Network<T> {
private Node source;
private Node target;
private ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();


public Graph(T source,T target) {
    this.source = new Node(source);
    this.target = new Node(target);


}


public T source() {
    return source.getData();
}

public T target() {
    return target.getData();
}
```

I get this error on source() and target(): required T found java.lang.Object why? the type of return of getData() function it's T(generic type of return)

Comment: Might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121179/casting-objects-to-t-type

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know they are the same `T`? You have to explicitly declare it as such: `Node<T> source; Node<T> target;`

Comment: @Obicere thanks it works!

Comment: @HKing Tom goes into a little more depth, but gets the same point across. You should accept that as the answer to help others figure this out as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Node source;
private Node target;
```

These should be `Node<T>`. Likewise on a few of the following lines. The compiler will have given you a warning. Take note of it. (When you mix raw types and generics, the Java Language Spec often requires the compiler to give up.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Node` with `Node<T>` in your `Graph` class

```
public class Graph<T> implements Network<T> {
    private Node<T> source;
    private Node<T> target;
    private ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public Graph(T source, T target) {
        this.source = new Node<T>(source);
        this.target = new Node<T>(target);

    }

    public T source() {
        return source.getData();
    }

    public T target() {
        return target.getData();
    }
}
```